# The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' .NET MVC 5 to .NET Core 3.1 MVC Migration

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-3.1

I have almost completed my migration from ASP.NET MVC 5 to .NET Core 3.1 and I am getting this error,

> The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assemble reference?).

The error is occurring in my `/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml` view, where I am setting the model.

```html
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Error"
}

<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
```

I have removed all of the AspNetCore packages and re-added them, and I have tried restarting my Visual Studio (VS19), all to no avail.

Perhaps the error handling has been moved out of the MVC package in .NET Core? That’s my best guess.

Comment: did you try to change it to `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In **ASP.NET Core 3.1**, the main namespace for a **MVC application** is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`. Try using that instead of `System.Web.Mvc`.

#### Error Handling in ASP.NET Core

That said, as far as error handling in particular is concerned, the approach has changed quite a bit from **ASP.NET Framework**, and the `HandleErrorInfo` class no longer exists. For more information on the new approach, see [Handle errors in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1). Instead of using the `HandleErrorInfo` class to retrieve information on an exception, for instance, you now use an implementation of `IExceptionHandlerPathFeature`—though there's a bit more to it than that, as covered in the documentation.

#### Migration Plan

Ultimately, this is just the first of many differences you're likely to run into when migrating to **ASP.NET Core**. Given that, I'd recommend reading through Microsoft's [Migrate from ASP.NET to ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/proper-to-2x/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) guide, which provides a useful summary of what has changed, and how to approach the migration.

#### Reference Project

In addition, assuming you're using **Visual Studio**, I'd recommend creating a new *ASP.NET Core Web Application* project, which will create a basic **ASP.NET Core 3.1** MVC application. This can be *really* useful to reference when performing a migration, as it establishes what a "text book" implementation *should* look like, and gives you an idea of what's changed and how to approach similar problems in the new framework.

#### Final Thoughts

Ultimately, a lot of the changes in **ASP.NET Core** are simply a matter of adding references to the correct **NuGet** packages, updating the namespaces, and, in a few cases, updating code to match changes in the class signatures. Still, there remain a number of areas where the old approaches (and the classes that supported them) no longer exist—as is the case here—and thus require additional thought and care.

Positively, this is a *lot* easier with **.NET Core 3.x** than it was with previous versions, as Microsoft has done a *ton* to close the feature parity gap between **.NET Framework** and **.NET Core** over the last four years. And, once you've finished the migration, I think you'll find your new site much cleaner and easier to maintain.